# how to avoid hard-coded template paths in angular js router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following code snippet in my angular router:

```
staticContent = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staticContent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

 $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
         url: "/Home",
        views: {
            "main-view": {
                //templateUrl: "../../../views/Home.htm",   --Case 1
                 templateUrl: staticContent+"/Home.htm",   --Case 2
                controller: "homeCtrl"

            }
        }
    })
```

Initially, I tried the above code for Case 1 and it is working fine. Problem with this is that I need to avoid the hard-coded path since my HTM files will be on a separate server.

However, when I use the code in Case 2, the application doesn't load at all. 
The variable **staticContent**   is set to **"../../../views"**. This value is getting read from a XML file(this value is set properly).
How can I avoid hard coded template paths in the router file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject constants into config blocks

```
angular.module('app', [])

.constant('STATIC_CONTENT', xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("staticContent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)

.config(function ($stateProvider, STATIC_CONTENT) {
  $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
     url: "/Home",
     views: {
        "main-view": {
             templateUrl: STATIC_CONTENT + "/Home.htm",
            controller: "homeCtrl"

        }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: awesome! but I am curious why wasnt the previous case working? It was just a simple javascript variable... its value must get appended in the state param rite?